# Why is there a space between my input boxes?

Tags: html, css

I have a set of input boxes, which I want to be nudged against each other, but for some reason there is a little bit of space between them, despite their container being display block, and there being no margin, padding, or border on the inputs.

```css
#container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
  <input type='number'>
</div>
```

Comment: See this blog post: https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all whitespaces between the inputs.

Tip: use class instead of id for css use.

```css
.container {
  height: 500px;
  background-color: blue;
  display: block;
}

input {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
      <input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'><input type='number'>
</div>
```